# Rails polymorphic association not available in models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphic-associations

I am new to rails so please bear with me, I've search all day on this.  Apologize if this is a beginner questions :)

I have a model with a polymorphic association defined:

```
class SocialLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :social, polymorphic: true
end
```

And two models that should have one of this association

```
class Staff < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  belongs_to :establishment
  has_one :image, as: :imageable
  has_one :social_link, as: :social
end


class Establishment < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_one :location
  has_one :social_link, as: :social
  has_many :staff

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff
end
```

Edit: initial table creation migration for social links

```
class CreateSocialLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :social_links do |t|
      t.string :facebook
      t.string :twitter
      t.string :yelp
      t.string :google_plus
      t.string :youtube
      t.string :instagram
      t.string :linkedin

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

The migration for this was created like so (Edit: please note the table existed at time of migration)

```
class AddSocialLinkReferenceToEstablishmentAndStaff < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :social_links, :social_links, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end


class UpdateSocialLinkReference < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_reference :social_links, :social_links
    add_reference :social_links, :social, polymorphic: true, index: true
  end
end
```

Edit: after the above migration, the social_id and social_type are available

```
#<SocialLink id: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, yelp: nil, google_plus: nil, youtube: nil, instagram: nil, linkedin: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, social_id: nil, social_type: nil>
```

However, for some reason the association isn't available on either of the models.  I am having trouble seeing what I have done wrong, it looks like I've set it up the same as another polymorphic association on an image model that is working

This one is working

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Thanks or the help!

Comment: What's exacty problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to access the association with the polymorphic name instead of just using the model name.  Instead of doing staff.social I should have used staff.social_link.  I got confused on this part.

Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

according to the [rails guide on polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) your migration should look more like this:

```
class CreateSocialLinks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :social_links do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :social, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

otherwise the table will be misssing

Comment: Hello @Stefan, the table already existed at the point of that migration.  You can see that the social_id and social_type columns are there after the migration I shared:

`#<SocialLink id: nil, facebook: nil, twitter: nil, yelp: nil, google_plus: nil, youtube: nil, instagram: nil, linkedin: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, social_id: nil, social_type: nil> `

Comment: i tried to reproduce this, but your migration above created the following
     #<SocialLink id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, social_links_id: nil, social_links_type: nil>

it should be social_id and social_type. (but otherwise you are right. sorry.)

Comment: Hey Stefan,  added an edit with the table creation code I used.  First the table was created, then I ran the migration that I listed to add the reference.  Hope this helps

Comment: i meant `add_reference :social_links, :social_links, polymorphic: true, index: true` should be `add_reference :social_links, :social, polymorphic: true, index: true`

Comment: Sorry Stefan, I missed a migration.  It was social_links polymorphic at first, but then I read that the polymorphic name shouldn't be the same as the table name, so I changed it to be just social.  Sorry for the confusion